# Selecting a max distinct value

Tags: sql

I have a database table with a phone number (string) and a name (string)

There same number may have different names in different rows

given a certain number I want to select the most frequently used name

For instance given the following data if using 555.1234 I should get back from the query Frank

```
Number   |  Name
-----------------
555.1234 |  Frank
555.1234 |  Fran
555.1234 |  James
555.1234 |  Frank
555.1233 |  Jesse
```

It seems like I should be able to combine distinct and Max somehow, but I can't come up with the right query to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: I believe its mysql, its actually behind a web service api.  if its not mysql its IBM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as I understand the question, you have a specific number as input, then this may work depending on the database you are using.  Capsule's comment made me realize that might not be the situation.  **Edit** Changed to Count(*) for (I think) better clarity based on Jack's good comment.

```
select Top 1 Name, Count(*) total 
   from phone where number = '555.1234' 
   group by name 
   order by total desc
```

Comment: Nice solution too if you know what phone number you're looking for, avoids to group by number first.

Comment: @Capsule:  I was reading the question as that being one of the conditions ... but I may well be wrong.  You make a good point.

Comment: No, I think you're right, I understand too this is one the conditions. I was commenting to compare your solution with jonwayne's one. You both deserve the acceptance ;-)

Comment: I do know the number that I am looking to match names for

Comment: It seems like this counts the total number of times a number is seen in the table and orders them based on that.  I want to count the number of times a name is seen in the table for a specific number and select the most frequently occurring name (or a row that contains that name) for that number.

Comment: @Jack: Since the results are filtered by the number, the result will be the same in either case.  In fact, I should have probably just used the generic `(*)` in this case.  It's just counting the grouped rows in either case. I will change it.

Comment: @Jack it counts the number of rows having the same Name because of  `group by name`. What you're stating is true without the group by clause.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know what the phone number will be to pass into the query, then you can use the following:

```
SELECT Number, Name, COUNT(Name) AS NameCount
FROM test
GROUP BY Number, Name
HAVING NameCount > 1
Order BY NameCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That will give you the most frequently used phone number by a single name, and return the phone, name and the count.

Here is the `test` table that I used to try out the query, and the values thereof:

```
Number   | Name
555.1234 | Frank
555.1234 | Fran
555.1234 | James
555.1234 | Frank
555.1234 | Jesse
555.2234 | Frank
555.1234 | Jesse
555.1234 | Frank
```

Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: how would you specify the number you want this information for?  simply add a where clause?

Comment: Exactly. You could add `WHERE Number = 'xxxxxxx'` after the FROM declaration.

Comment: Then you may want to group only by name.

Comment: This query was crafted assuming the number was unknown. If known, go with Mr. Wilkins' recommendation.